# Making a dataframe from a list of files with different target class columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a list of text files:

```
['datasets/Autobiography.txt',
 'datasets/CoralReefs.txt',
 'datasets/DescentofMan.txt',
 'datasets/DifferentFormsofFlowers.txt',
 'datasets/EffectsCrossSelfFertilization.txt']
```

They all have 'text' and 'labels' columns, with 'labels' having 2 classes (yes/no).

I am creating a dataframe with all the file names and their relevant information.

For example, I am extracting how many rows in each file:

```
rows = []
for i in files:
    rows.append(i.shape[0])
```

Then I am making the dataframe with file name and notes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(file_name=files_list, notes_number=rows))
```

I also want to put label class (yes/no) into different columns along with the file names.

```
file_name  notes_number   yes   no
 AAAA.txt      100        50    50
 BBBB.txt      200        100   100
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've got most of the solution already. Thanks for writing such a good question!

> I also want to put label class (yes/no) into different columns along with the file names.

You can do this with [Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

> ```py
> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(file_name=files_list, notes_number=rows))
> ```

When I'm iteratively building up a dataframe, I like to use a list of dictionaries. I find it easier to read than a dictionary of lists. It's also more performant than appending a row at a time to a dataframe. Here's how I would do what you're suggesting:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

filenames = ['foo.csv', 'foo2.csv']
summaries = []

for file in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    counts = df['labels'].value_counts()
    summary = {
        'filename': file,
        'notes_number': df.shape[0],
        'yes': counts['yes'],
        'no': counts['no'],
    }
    summaries.append(summary)

summaries = pd.DataFrame(summaries)
print(summaries)
```

Which gives this output:

```
   filename  notes_number  yes  no
0   foo.csv           100   52  48
1  foo2.csv            70   36  34
```

---

Edit: If you want to support multiple kinds of labels, here's how to modify the example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

filenames = ['foo.csv', 'foo2.csv']
summaries = []

for file in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    summary = {
        'filename': file,
        'notes_number': df.shape[0],
    }
    # Add value counts to summary
    counts = df['labels'].value_counts()
    summary.update(counts.to_dict())
    summaries.append(summary)

summaries = pd.DataFrame(summaries)
# Fill in missing values
summaries = summaries.fillna(0)
print(summaries)
```

This produces the following output:

```
   filename  notes_number  yes  no  maybe
0   foo.csv           100   51  48    1.0
1  foo2.csv            70   36  34    0.0
```

The 'maybe' class exists in foo.csv, but not in foo2.csv, but we can fill in the missing value with the `fillna(0)` line.

Comment: Hi @Nick-Odell. That's really a smart way of building up dataframe. Thank you :)

I would like to know one more thing -- if I have more than 2 classes and that too differ file to file, in that case, how can I iterate over the files and make target class columns with those classes?

Comment: Do you mean that there are multiple values in the labels column, or that you have multiple columns that you want to get values from?

Comment: There are multiple values in the labels column, and the number differs file to file.

Comment: @Roy You can convert the value counts to a dict, and include them into the new dataframe. See edit.

Comment: Didn't get that. Any example?

Comment: @Roy Look at the edit I made to the post 13 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65330783/revisions

Comment: Wow! That's a new lesson to me. Thank you so much @Nick!